# File export in jquery datatables using dropdown change event

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables, dropdown

I developed a functionality for file export using `JQuery Datatable Collections`. When I click on a button e.g PDF (see image below), it exports Datatable as PDF file.

[image]

**Here Is My Code for that.**

```
buttons: [
   {
       extend: 'collection',
       text: 'Save & Column Visibility',
       autoClose: true,
       buttons: [
                   { text: 'Copy', extend: 'copyHtml5'},
                   { text: 'Excel', extend: 'excelHtml5'},
                   { text: 'CSV', extend: 'csvHtml5'},
                   { text: 'PDF', extend: 'pdfHtml5'},
                   { text: 'Print', extend: 'print' }

                ],
            fade: true,
   }
],
```

My requirement is to implement this functionality on drop-down change event instead of button click event.

**Here is my code for drop-down i have done so far.**

```
$('<div class="pull-right">' +
        '<select id="dropdown" name="dropdown" class="form-control">' +
        '<option value="copy">Copy</option>' +
        '<option value="excel">Excel</option>' +
        '<option value="csv">CSV</option>' +
        '<option value="pdf">PDF</option>' +
        '<option value="print">print</option>' +
        '</select>' +
        '</div>').appendTo("#tbMenu_wrapper .dataTables_filter");
    $(".dataTables_filter label").addClass("pull-right");
});
```

**Here is the Function for Onchange Event which I have created For Testing Purpose.**

```
$(function () {

        $("#dropdown").change(function () {

            if ($(this).val() == "copy") {
                alert("From Copy");


            }
            else if ($(this).val() == "excel") {
                alert("From excel");

            }
            else if ($(this).val() == "csv") {
                alert("From csv");
            }
            else if ($(this).val() == "pdf") {
                alert("From pdf");
            }
            else if ($(this).val() == "print") {
                alert("From print");
            } else {
                alert("From else part");
            }
        });
```

It works fine when I click on Drop-down value and gives me alert as specified in function. But now what should I do in above mentioned code which will give me file export functionality on Drop-down change event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Found Solution For My Question Which I am Sharing For Future Reference.
Just Replace this line  `alert("From Copy");` with this

```
var table = $('#tbMenu').DataTable();
table.button('.buttons-copy').trigger();
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It should work OOTB, you require dependencies to be loaded.

> Buttons provides button types that will automatically determine if
> HTML5 or Flash should be used based on the browser's functionality and
> it is strongly recommended that you use these button types over the
> specific HTML5 or Flash button types. These are: copy, csv, excel,
> pdf.
>
> This example shows those four button types, plus print, being used
> with all required dependencies being loaded.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
        ]
    } );
} );
```

Please refer to :

https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/export.html
https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/